# Javascript - id's are timestamps, if more than 10 then delete the oldest one

Tags: javascript, jquery

A bit of a tricky one, at least for me.  Here is the scenario:

```
<div id="gifs"> 
<img src="gif/1.jpg" alt="" >
<img src="gif/10.jpg" alt="" >
<img src="gif/15.jpg" alt="" >
<img src="gif/20.jpg" alt="" >
<img src="gif/5.jpg" alt="" >
</div>
```

Everytime a user clicks on an image, the image changes to a gif and the id is set with a timestamp.
The issues is, I don't want more than 4 gifs at a time.  Which means that, if there are 4 gifs, next time a user clicks, the older one goes back to being a jpg.  HOW CAN I DO THAT?

Here is my jquery so far:

```
$("#gifs img").click(function () { 
        var original = $(this).attr("src"); 
        var newsrc = original.replace('jpg','gif');
        if(!$(this).hasClass('on')){
            $(this).attr("src" , '');
            $(this).attr("src", newsrc );
            $(this).addClass('on');

            var t = new Date();
            var time = t.getTime(); 

            $(this).attr('id' , time);

            // HELP MOSTLY HERE, IN THE EACH FUNCTION.  NEED TO STORE TIMESTAMP INSIDE AN ARRAY...
            $('.on').each(function(e){

                //dif[] = $(e).attr('id');

            });

            /*var oldest = dif.min();

            var oldestsrc = $('#'+oldest).attr("src"); 
            var oldestnewsrc = oldestsrc.replace('gif','jpg');
             $('#'+oldest).attr("src",oldestnewsrc); */
        }
});
```

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Basically, I'm having problems on the each function.  That should stock the timestamps, get the oldest one if the array length is more than 4, and switch it back to a jpg...

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you're using timestamps.  Are they needed later for some reason?  If not, this would be MUCH easier with a global counter variable that just increments by 1 each time something is clicked.

Comment: I use the timestamp to find which one is the oldest.

Comment: A timestamp isn't really required for this if you look at some of the other suggestions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
(function () {
    // cache images so that we can use them later
    var $imgs = $("#gifs img");
    $imgs.click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass("on")) {
            // get all IDs of those images that are "on"
            var ids = Array.prototype.slice.call($imgs.filter(".on").map(function () { return this.id; }));
            if (ids.length >= 3) {
                // get oldest image by sorting the IDs in ascending order and get the first
                var $oldest = $("#"+ids.sort()[0]);
                // change oldest image
                $oldest.attr("src", function () { return this.src.replace("gif", "jpg"); });
                $oldest.removeClass("on");
            }
            // change for clicked image
            $this.attr("id", new Date().getTime());
            $this.attr("src", function () { return this.src.replace("jpg", "gif"); });
            $this.addClass("on");
        }
    });
})();
```

The whole is wrapped in a function to not to pollute the global variable scope.

Comment: Interesting...I can't understand everything, but it seems like it is missing a counter of the sort (4 gis max animated at the time).  How would you do that?

Comment: @denislexic: I’ve added some comments; hope that helps.

Comment: using sort for something like this should set off warning bells somewhere.

Comment: @Dasuraga, You have two options for determining the oldest element in a list. You can sort by timestamp/age, or use a queue and pull changed elements from the bottom and put them on the top. Either way, you're sorting (active vs passive). Using "sort" should allow adding new elements dynamically without having to add them to a queue, etc. I believe sort is the most flexible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am far from a javascript expert, but I think I get your dilemma. What you might be interested in is a [Circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer):

The idea would be that you'd keep this array set up that would store the (up to) 4 ids relating to your image expansion stuff(I'll get to the unitialized stuff later):

```
var gifs=['uninitialized','uninitialized','uninitialized','uninitialized'];
```

The trick is how you access this array. Let's add another variable:

```
var currentIndex=0;
```

The idea is that you just want to have a list of 4 elements, and if you add a fifth, you'll replace the oldest one. Here's an idea of how the access works:

let's add 'a':

```
['a','uninitialized','uninitialized','uninitializedl']
       ^ currentIndex
```

now let's throw on 'b' and 'c':

```
['a','b','c','uninitialized']
               ^ currentIndex
```

Now here comes the tricky part. So far we've been incrementing currentIndex by one(or so we thought). Let's see what happens when we add 'd' :

```
[ 'a' ,'b','c','d']
   ^ currentIndex
```

Thus the "circular" in circular buffer. When you add enough elements into the array, the index goes back to the beginning. Truly magnificent. If you're wondering how easy this is, it is not too complicated. To "increment" currentIndex while having it loop around, no "if"s are necessary:

```
currentIndex=(currentIndex+1)%4
```

(replace 4 with whatever buffer length you want, obviously)

But what happens if we want to put in another element? like (to choose a random letter), if we try to add 'e'?:

```
[ 'e' , 'b' , 'c', 'd'] 
         ^ curentIndex
```

Well, the array wasn't going to magically expand, so instead it replaced 'a' (the oldest element to be added) with 'e'.  Thus the utility to the problem.

If I were attacking this problem , I'd implement something along the following (assuming I've defined the previous stuff):

```
function addGif(id){
    if(gifs[currentIndex]=='uninitialized')//We haven't gotten to 4 gifs yet, no magic necessary
         gifs[currentIndex]=id;
    else{//we've reached 4 gifs, so now it's time for some "magic"
           //do whatever you need to do with the oldest gif(at currentIndex)
           removeGif(gifs[currentIndex]);//obviously this function will need to be written
          gifs[currentIndex]=id;
   }
    //don't forget to increment the index!
    currentIndex=(currentIndex+1)%buffer;
}
```

And bam! No ugly DOM techniques, just some good old-fashioned simple programming-language-agnostic solution. And it is somewhat constant time (unlike sorting entire tags). You don't even need to bother with timestamps really, just give your things some sort of 'unique' ids(you could even use a circular buffer to assign ids to your tags!)

(Circular buffers usually have a bit more boilerplate for accessing elements and whatnot, but here I just tried to stick to the necessary. Hope it wasn't simplified to the point where the concept is lost)

Sorry for my bad Javascript, I'm a foreigner when it comes to webdev.

Comment: I had the idea to use a stack of 4 elements and pop the oldest element but this circular buffer here seems to avoid having the pop anything so that is quite nice.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up an array to store the information for the four you are currently displaying, then use this information to know when you already have four and which one to remove when full.  That's at least the naive answer:  maybe there's some more clever way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here just the part of the .each()

```
var stamps = new Array();
  $('.on').each(function(e){
    stamps[] = $(e).attr('id');
  });

  if (${stamps.length}>4){
      stamps.sort(function sortNumber(a,b){return b - a;})
        for (var i=4;i<stamps.length;i++) 
        {
          $(e).remove()
        }
  }
```

It sorts the timestamps in reverse order and remove everything past 4 stamps.

Enjoy =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding of what you want using javascript array push and shift functions

http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/UcDAV/

Could probably tidy this up a little bit

```
$(function() {

var gifs = $('img[src$=gif]').get(); // Get all gifs
$('#images img').click(function() {
    console.log(gifs);
    var img = $(this);
    var src = img.attr('src');
    img.attr('src', src.replace('jpg', 'gifs'));
    if (gifs.indexOf(this) === -1) {
        gifs.push(this);
    }
    if (gifs.length > 4) {
        var last = gifs.shift();
        src = $(last).attr('src');
        $(last).attr('src', src.replace('gif', 'jpg'));
    }
    console.log(gifs);
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#gifs img").click(function () { 
        var original = $(this).attr("src"); 
        var newsrc = original.replace('.jpg','.gif');
        if(!$(this).hasClass('on')){
            $(this).attr("src" , '');
            $(this).attr("src", newsrc );
            $(this).addClass('on');

            var t = new Date();
            var time = t.getTime();

            $(this).attr('id' , time);

            var minimum = time;
            var counter = 0;
            $('.on').each(function(){ 

                counter = counter +1;   
                var current  = $(this).attr('id')*1;  

                if( current <= minimum ){ minimum = $(this).attr('id')*1; }

            });

            if(counter >= 10){ 
                var oldestsrc = $('#'+minimum).attr("src"); 
                var oldestnewsrc = oldestsrc.replace('.gif','.jpg');
                $('#'+minimum).attr("src",oldestnewsrc);
                $('#'+minimum).removeClass('on');
                $('#'+minimum).attr('id','');

                counter = 0;
            }


        }
});
```